# How to indent xml in emacs like intellij?

Tags: xml, emacs, intellij-idea

Android Studio creates boilerplate xml code that looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">
```

OTOH indenting it via emacs aligns all siblings with each other, which takes up too much space and makes life tough for me in a team full of intellij users.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MyActivity">
```

How do I configure emacs for indenting xml like this? I'm out of words to frame a google search for this problem.

Comment: Which mode are you using? Most modes have a standard variable or set of variables for specifying static or relative indentation preferences. Quick googling turns up e.g. [this](http://glblack.livejournal.com/6594.html) but it's for `sgml-mode`.

Answer (score 4):

[web-mode.el](http://web-mode.org) does that by default

Comment: Thanks, looks useful. I'll check it out.

Comment: what do you mean ? have you installed web-mode ? gave you associated *.xml files with web-mode ?

Comment: Installed web-mode and activated it in an xml file to test.